# Unable to convert .fbx file to .glb file

Tags: animation, export, .fbx, gltf, three.js

I am new to Blender and I am stuck in converting .fbx to .glb file.
My objective is to export two animations (without skin) to .glb file which can be used in three.js
I can merge two animations in a single file (below is the screenshot).

[image]

But when I am exporting this to a .glf file I cannot see the armature yet there is the same armature inside the .glf file and it shows only a dot when importing the .glb file.

[image]

And i tried to import the into three.js animation, i cannot see the animation yet animations are loaded.

[image]

Below is the link of the merged animation file and both .fbx files.

https://we.tl/t-grWt6wmRfB

Can you please help me with the problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The download link seems to have expired, but I don't think it's possible to export a valid armature without any mesh in glTF. It might be best to try this with a simple mesh — even a cube — first. You can always discard the mesh later in three.js.